# a link not working in jquery ajax search box

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using a search box to show the result from the database using jquery ajax function to show the result. The result showing correctly but a link is not working.

The `<a` link is not working

**Script**

```
$("#searchid").click(function() {
  $('#results').find('li').remove();
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url()?>Home/search1',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    //data: {},

    success: function(response) {
      //$('#results').html(data);
      for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $("#results").append("<li><a href='" + response[i].name + "'>" + response[i].name + "</a></li>");
      }

    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Fail");
    }
  });


  return false;
});


$("#searchid").keyup(function() {
  var searchid = $(this).val();
  $('#results').find('li').remove();
  //var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
  if (searchid != '') {
    //alert("hello");
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url()?>Home/search1',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        searchid: searchid
      },

      success: function(response) {
        //$('#results').html(data);
        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          $("#results").append("<li><a href='" + response[i].name + "'>" + response[i].name + "</a></li>");
        }

      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Fail");
      }
    });

  }
  return false;
});

< /script>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  color: #404040;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
}
a {
  color: #1e7ad3;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}
.main {
  margin-top: 50px
}
input {
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #555860;
}
#search {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#search input {
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a8acbc #babdcc #c0c3d2;
  border-radius: 13px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
}
#search input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #66b1ee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
}
#search input:focus + #results {
  display: block
}
#search #results {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfdfd), color-stop(100%, #eceef4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#search #results li {
  display: block
}
#search #results li:first-child {
  margin-top: -1px
}
#search #results li:first-child:before,
#search #results li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border: 5px outset transparent;
}
#search #results li:first-child:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
  top: -11px;
}
#search #results li:first-child:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
  top: -10px;
}
#search #results li:first-child:hover:before,
#search #results li:first-child:hover:after {
  display: none
}
#search #results li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: -1px
}
#search #results a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -1px;
  padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
  color: #808394;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#search #results a span {
  font-weight: 200
}
#search #results a:before {
  content: '';
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  background: url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7BNkBjd.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#search #results a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-color: #2380dd #2179d5 #1a60aa;
  background-color: #338cdf;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
 :-moz-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.lt-ie9 #search input {
  line-height: 26px
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="search" method="post" action="index.html">
  <input type="text" name="q" id="searchid" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for event, hotel, restaurant, job ... " />
  <ul id="results">

  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Any errors in console?

Comment: What's the value of `response[i].name` ? Is it a valid path or URI? What do you want to accomplish in the end? Calling a function, or redirecting to another page? Please clearify some of this, it should be easier to help you out then! :)

Comment: not error in console my error is only that it show the expected links using ajax but when i try to click on the links it does not showing any responce.

Comment: i have change $("#results").append("<li><a href='index.html'>" + response[i].name + "</a></li>"); but the link is not working no click event happening after ajax response is their any css or jquery issue becuase i using keyup and click event plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are adding the name instead of the URL as the href attribute?

```
 $("#results").append("<li><a href='" + response[i].name + "'>" + response[i].name + "</a></li>");
```

Comment: yes i am using name but when i click on the ajax response at least it have to return an url.